# How do I know if my Windws 10 version (Home) edition has SSL support?

Tags: windows-10, ssl, setup, mongodb

Context: 
I am tryin to install MongoDB and saw there are seperate installers for Windows 2008 or later with SSL support and one without SSL support. My machine runs 64-bit Windows 10 Home edition.

"SSL === Secure Sockets Layer" as I found out on google.

Now, how would I know, if my OS has SSL support, or not? (Also, what does it mean to have SSL support? From a user / web dev perspective?)  Or is that a lame question?

Can someone throw some light on that?

Comment: As I mentioned on chat - I'm a little confused since its a fundamental technology used in a lot of 'trivial' encryption implementations and *client* support is ubiquitous.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I *suspect* that might be the reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The choice indicates whether you want the version with SSL support or not.

SSL (or TLS) is an encryption method used for online communications.  You've probably seen it many times on web sites (using `https`), but it is also used for many other protocols.

If your DB is for local access only, then it would be more trouble to configure and require more resources for nothing to use SSL, but if you make it available from the outside, it is a very good idea to encrypt it.

The MongoDB manual contains [good instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/) on installing it with SSL support.

Answer (score 2):

OSes don't typically have SSL support 'baked in'. You might have libraries shipped default with the OS, or SSL libraries preinstalled. However, very often, applications may depend on specific versions or implimentations of the SSL libraries to work. Most copies of windows come with necessary *client* libraries for native or preinstalled applications that need it.

Software often *also* has the option of being built with SSL. Being built with SSL means you have SSL support, which is typically what you want, unless you don't. You can do non ssl connections (say if your db and application are on the same or on trusted hosts which are locked on) or ssl connections (over the internet) with a SSL enabled client.

That said, SSL is a *fundamental* technology used in web servers. HTTPS? ssl. Most 'trivial' point to point web encryption? ssl.

Windows 10 home probably isn't the best choice for development here either, but that's a whole different argument.